# How To convert UTC TIMESTAMP only, into local time, on the web with javascript? from http://openweathermap.org/

Tags: javascript, html, time, utc

I am using the Weather APi found here: http://openweathermap.org/

The Sunrise and Sunset come back as numerical objects such as :

1. 1425951068 (sunset okotoks, ab, can)
2. 1425909686 (sunrise okotoks, ab, can)

I have tried all the methods i could find, but still no luck, as the majority of methods are looking for a complete UTC date, not just a UTC Time.

How can i convert this with javascript, into the user's local time zone?

Comment: What's your desired output?

Comment: Use javascript [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) API. Those numbers are tics (milliseconds since the Epoch).

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for the information - @Leo the desired output would be just the TIME of day

Comment: `(new Date(1425909686)).toLocaleTimeString()`

Comment: @Leo that is super incorrect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If all you want is local time (no date info) then Leo is right. I had incorrectly stated milliseconds but unix tick units are actually seconds so we must multiply by 1000 to construct a correct javascript Date.

```js
var sec = 1425909686;
var date = new Date(sec * 1000);
var timestr = date.toLocaleTimeString();

console.log(date, timestr);

$("#d1").html(date);
$("#d2").html(timestr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="d1"></div>
<div id="d2"></div>
```

Comment: There we go, it was the times 1000 that did the trick. thank you.  How did you figure this out?

Comment: If you print the current date as ticks you see very similar numbers but it's off by 000. The weather api states "unix date" but not units so I double checked on the interwebs (wikipedia) to verify seconds rather than milliseconds as units.